# why get 404 error when the PHP echo position is changed

Tags: php, http-post, http-status-code-404

```
<?php

define('PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/');
require_once (PATH.'./wp-blog-header.php');
global $wpdb;




// if(!isset($_POST['username'])){
//  //echo $_POST['submit'];
//  exit('非法访问!');

// }

$username   = $_POST["username"];
$password   = $_POST["password"];
$email      = $_POST["email"];
$checkcode  = $_POST["checkcode"];



$query_pwd_str = "SELECT password FROM yjhy_users_custom WHERE username=%s";


if($wpdb == null)
    echo "wpdb is null";

$pwd_query_result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($query_pwd_str, $username));





$pwd_query_result_count = count($pwd_query_result);

if($pwd_query_result_count == 1){

    //已经存在该用户名，返回数据
     // error here
     header('Content-type:text/json');
     $json_ouput = '{"status":"success","errormsg":"'.$username.'"}';
     echo $json_ouput;


}


?>
```

With the code above, I use method `post` to refer to the php file, and it ALWAYS responsed with 404 Error.

But, when I modify PHP code as BELOW:

```
<?php
  //****************** move the function header() here
  header('Content-type:text/json');
  //******************  echo "{" here
  echo "{";

?>
<?php

define('PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/');
require_once (PATH.'./wp-blog-header.php');
global $wpdb;




// if(!isset($_POST['username'])){
//  //echo $_POST['submit'];
//  exit('非法访问!');

// }

$username   = $_POST["username"];
$password   = $_POST["password"];
$email      = $_POST["email"];
$checkcode  = $_POST["checkcode"];



$query_pwd_str = "SELECT password FROM yjhy_users_custom WHERE username=%s";


if($wpdb == null)
    echo "wpdb is null";

$pwd_query_result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($query_pwd_str, $username));





$pwd_query_result_count = count($pwd_query_result);

if($pwd_query_result_count == 1){

    //已经存在该用户名，返回数据
     // error here

     $json_ouput = '"status":"success","errormsg":"'.$username.'"';
     echo $json_ouput;


}


?>

<?php
  //******************  echo "}" here
  echo "}";

?>
```

AND THEN, it works, the server response status is 200!

I'm puzzled about this problem, and have searched all day and can't find the answer!

Why does the code work like this?

Comment: What is the content of `require_once (PATH.'./wp-blog-header.php');` ? Is it displaying something or simply php code without output ?

Comment: require_once (PATH.'./wp-blog-header.php');
I use WordPress framework, and use the $wpdb object provided by WP, so need that line. @zeflex

Comment: Ok but what is the content of this file ? Does it also displays html code ?

Comment: `wp-blog-header.php` is here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-blog-header.php#L0
AND all the framework `WordPress` 's code is here:https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src
 @zeflex

Comment: Can you edit `/wp-includes/template-loader.php` and add at line 72 : `var_dump($template); die();` then run your code again. If you have a value displayed here, your error could be generated because something is displayed before your json output.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I use xdebug to follow the code track, and find it out in `wp-includes/class-wp.php`. IF with the first code, the WP framework response a 404 error when it execute in `class-wp.php`. And I still get the json data from server although with 404 error. Why this? when you requert a link, the WP will check the link in the link-order of the `"post" "page"' you created in the `dashboard`. And my link is not in the order because I refer the `.php` directly with the file path. So, I get the 404 from the `require_once (PATH.'./wp-blog-header.php');`. @zeflex

Comment: With the second code, the code `echo "{";` response a 200 status before the `require_once (PATH.'./wp-blog-header.php');` response a 404 status. So that's why!

Answer (score 1):

With 1 days' time, I find it out!
I request the link with the file path `http://localhost:7770/api/register.php` directly rather than request link by creating a `page` in the Dashboard, so the link is not in the WP's database. 
And WP framework need to initialize itself when execute `wp();` in the `require_once (PATH.'./wp-blog-header.php');`, but when the initial action execute in the file `/wp-includes/class-wp.php` with code below:

```
public function main($query_args = '') {
        $this->init();
        **$this->parse_request($query_args);**
        $this->send_headers();
        $this->query_posts();
        $this->handle_404();
        $this->register_globals();
        do_action_ref_array( 'wp', array( &$this ) );
    }

 }
```

the statement `$this->query_posts();` need to check the link `$this->parse_request();`.  the func `parse_request()`:

```
public function parse_request($extra_query_vars = '') {
        global $wp_rewrite;

        /**
         * Filter whether to parse the request.
         *
         * @since 3.5.0
         *
         * @param bool         $bool             Whether or not to parse the request. Default true.
         * @param WP           $this             Current WordPress environment instance.
         * @param array|string $extra_query_vars Extra passed query variables.
         */
        if ( ! apply_filters( 'do_parse_request', true, $this, $extra_query_vars ) )
            return;

        $this->query_vars = array();
        $post_type_query_vars = array();

        if ( is_array( $extra_query_vars ) ) {
            $this->extra_query_vars = & $extra_query_vars;
        } elseif ( ! empty( $extra_query_vars ) ) {
            parse_str( $extra_query_vars, $this->extra_query_vars );
        }
        // Process PATH_INFO, REQUEST_URI, and 404 for permalinks.

        // Fetch the rewrite rules.
        $rewrite = $wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules();

        if ( ! empty($rewrite) ) {
            // If we match a rewrite rule, this will be cleared.

            ***$error = '404';***
            $this->did_permalink = true;

            $pathinfo = isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : '';
            list( $pathinfo ) = explode( '?', $pathinfo );
            $pathinfo = str_replace( "%", "%25", $pathinfo );

            list( $req_uri ) = explode( '?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
            $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            $home_path = trim( parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_PATH ), '/' );
```

And the link is not in the database, so WP set the error 404 here below:

And then I get the `error 404`in `***$error = '404';***`!

resolve solution:

1. create a `page` in the Dashboard.
2. modify the `page` url you want.
3. put your code in the `page template`.
4. use `this template` in the `page`.
5. and Ok